# How to color section numbers in the TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, color

In the following MWE, how can I color just section numbers in the TOC?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}}  
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test one}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Foo bar}

‎\end{document}‎
```

I like to do that without using an additional package such as `tocloft`.

Comment: What's wrong with `tocloft`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No packages, just redefine or change the way `\csname the#1\endcsname` is written to the ToC, by redefinition of `\@sect`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}}  

\newcommand{\sectionnumbercolor}{blue}

\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
  \fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #6{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
          \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
    \endgroup
    \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
      \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
        \protect\numberline{\textcolor{\sectionnumbercolor}{\csname the#1\endcsname}}%
      \fi
      #7}%
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{%
      #6{\hskip #3\relax
      \@svsec #8}%
      \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
        \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
          \protect\numberline{\textcolor{\sectionnumbercolor}{\csname the#1\endcsname}}%
        \fi
        #7}}%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#5}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test one}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Foo bar}

‎\end{document}‎
```

[image]

Comment: I was about to add the picture myself. :P +1 by the way

Comment: @Alenanno: I was distracted for a while

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Thanks for your answer, but when I change the `book` to `tufte-book` class, your code doesn't work! I want the answer for `tufte-book` class in fact. I didn't think the class matter. sorry:-(

Comment: @Sisabe: Well, that's your fault, sorry!!!! -- you wrote `without` packages, so I opted for standard `book`, as you provided.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I asked a [follow-up question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311972/how-to-color-just-the-section-numbers-in-the-toc-in-the-tufte-book-class). Please help me!

Answer (score 3):

The following introduces a patch that changes the `\numberline` macro that's typically written to the ToC. Instead a macro specific to the sectional unit is written, which in turn can be defined to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\numberline}{\csname #1numberline\endcsname}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\numberline}{\csname #1numberline\endcsname}{}{}
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother

\colorlet{secnumcolor}{red}% For convenience

% Default definition of \numberline (left-aligned box of fixed-width \@tempdima)
% \def\numberline#1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1\hfil}}

\newcommand{\sectionnumberline}[1]{\makebox[2.3em][l]{\color{secnumcolor}#1}}
%\newcommand{\subsectionnumberline}{\numberline}% Not needed here
%\newcommand{\subsubsectionnumberline}{\numberline}% Not needed here

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test one}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Foo bar}

‎\end{document}‎
```

We perform the patch `\numberline` > `\csname #1numberline\endcsname` twice to cover both instances inside `\@sect`. [`regexpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch) would be able to do this in a single command as a *replace all*.