# How to color just the section numbers in the Toc in the tufte-book class?

Tags: table-of-contents, color, tufte

> This is a follow-up question to [How to color section numbers in the
>   TOC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311958/how-to-color-section-numbers-in-the-toc)

How to adopt the answers in the link above to work in the `tufte-book` class? here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[notoc,numbers]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}}  
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test one}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Foo bar}

‎\end{document}‎
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`tufte-book`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex) uses the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) and [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) pair to manage the sectional and their ToC-related entries. As such, we just need to change the appropriate `\titleformat{section}` entry inside [`tufte-common.def`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/tufte-common.def) to get the desired result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[notoc,numbers]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Taken from http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/tufte-common.def
\titlecontents{section}% FIXME
  [0em] % distance from left margin
  {\rmfamily} % above (global formatting of entry)
  {\hspace*{2em}\textcolor{red}{\contentslabel{2em}}} % before w/label (label = ``2.6'')
  {\hspace*{2em}} % before w/o label
  {\titlerule*[0.7em]{.}\rmfamily\upshape\contentspage} % filler + page (leaders and page num)
  [] % after

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test one}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Foo bar}

‎\end{document}‎
```

Comment: Hello, I believe your answer might answer my question as I had implemented it and I managed to get it work for the section. How do I also apply this format for subsections? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619006/how-to-remove-the-italics-from-the-table-of-content-for-tufte-handout